# Optimizing Redshift Query Performance with Large IN Clause and Large Columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm working with an Amazon Redshift database and encountering performance issues with queries that involve a large IN clause (or equivalent multiple OR conditions) to fetch multiple IDs. The typical query pattern is as follows:

```sql
SELECT id, colA, colB FROM tableName WHERE id IN ('id_A', 'id_B', ..., 'id_N');
```

In these queries, colA is particularly large, often on the order of megabytes. The execution time for such queries is unusually high, taking anywhere from 2 to 5 minutes each.

Our table configuration is:

```
Sortkey: AUTO(SORTKEY(id))
Diststyle: AUTO(EVEN)
skew_sortkey1: 17.32
```

Additionally, our cluster details are:

```
Storage used: 65.02% (416.13 of 640 GB used)
Node type: dc2.large
Number of nodes: 4
```

I suspect that the high skew_sortkey1 value might be due to the large size of colA, necessitating the retrieval of multiple storage blocks.

To address this, I'm considering changing the diststyle to KEY(id), theorizing that this might colocate id and colA on the same cluster node, potentially reducing the skew_sortkey1 value.

Would this approach be effective in improving query performance? Or is there another, more efficient solution to this issue?

(Edited)

[Query Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipjrr.png)

[stl_scan of a query with where clause with single id(took this 2min)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BPpf.png)

Comment: can you paste the query plan please?

Comment: @MitchWheat
```
Seq Scan on works (cost=0.00..8552999.28 rows=122185704 width=121)
```

I'm not sure what to copy-paste but is this enough??

Thanks for your response Mitch!!

Comment: @MitchWheat
I don't have a specific reason. 
Our team has limited knowledge of Redshift, and I have been running it with default settings. 
I only became aware of terms like skew_sortkey and diststyle yesterday, since we realized that our query is slow.

Do you think changing diststyle to key on Id will make this query faster??

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the sortkey skew is likely due to the size of values in colA.  This would then mean that more blocks of colA would be needed for each block of id that has a zone map that matches the the where clause.

One way to address this, if you haven't already, is to uncompress the id column so that each value takes up more space. This reduces the skew and possibly reduces the number of blocks that will match the where clause.

There may be other issues at play here.  Is the query only slow for SELECT but not for CTAS?  Retrieving a lot of data out the JDBC connection can also create significant delays in such cases.  Run CREATE TEMP TABLE AS SELECT ... and see if this makes a difference.

Changing the distkey to id would be bad.  This will make only the slices with matching ids able to respond and this will reduce the available power of the cluster.

If these steps don't clarify what is going on there are a few additional diagnostic steps to take.  Reviewing stl_scan, stl_return etc.

Comment: As you know, the leading column of a sortkey should never be compressed.  Where does the OP say Id column is compressed? (I must have missed it)

Comment: Thanks Bill!

I queried to see if id is compressed and turns out it's not.(colA is compressed with zstd)

Well, even with single "where id = 'XXX'" clause made our query slow(~2min), so it's not the problem with JDBC connection I guess.

Our main usecase for this Redshift is just to search using id, so changing the distkey might be a one solution to our usecase?

Thanks for your help too, @MitchWheat !!

Comment: Setting distkey to id will make things worse especially when querying a single (few) ids.  How many rows are returned with a single id where clause? 1? If this is taking 2 min then there is something else going on.  Is the table metadata up to date?  Is the sortkey really id?  Is the table sorted (vacuumed)?  If pulling 1 row is taking 2 min then it could be that the whole table needs to be scanned to get this one row.  Look at stl_scan to verify.  If not a metadata issue then ...

Comment: @BillWeiner

id is the unique id so single row is returned with a single id.

- Is the sortkey really id?
 - Yes, it is set to AUTO(KEY(id)).
- Is it vaccumed?
 - Yes, I manually ran "VACUME  table_name" and it was done with a few hours.
 - I re-run the vacume and verify it ended with in a sec(should be sorted).

I have added the pic of stl_scan on the OP, so it would be really appriciated if you could take a look at it(I am going to search for the concepts of that stats data too)

Comment: Other concerns I come up with now.

- All entries in the id column of my table share a common, lengthy prefix (like "https : //example.com/A123456", where '123456' is the unique part of the ID)

- Additionally, I am not using interleaved sort keys. I'm considering if using an interleaved sort key instead of my current sort key strategy would help improve performance given the structure of my IDs.

Comment: Also noticed that when I execute

```
explain select colA from table_name order by id limit 100;
```
show that sortkey is used, but not used when I use where id = 'XXX' somehow.

Comment: This is why it is important to share DDL and to not make assumptions like id is a number type.  Block metadata contains min and max value for the column per block.  This is a bigint value no matter what the type of the column.  For text type columns this bigint is based on the first 8 characters of the data.  So based on what you are describing there will be no difference in any of the id column metadata making it useless.  You can confirm this by looking at stv_blocklist - minvalue and maxvalue for the id column.

Comment: @BillWeiner
Thank you so much for your deep insight. You're totally correct and I really should have added the DDL from the beginning...my bad.

I did query to stv_blocklist and yes, the min and max had the same number.

Then now, I have two options.

1. Create a new column, "int_id(bigint)" and insert it using "id(string)"

2. Use Interleaved Sort. I found the official doc said, "an interleaved sort might give better performance than a compound sort if the column values have a long common prefix." and this must be excatly the pattern we faced.

Comment: I'd lean away from interleaved sort key as this comes with some downsides - reindexing, vacuum times, and not being sure how well it would do with only 1 interleaved sortkey.  Not that the other option is without issues.  I'd make a column where you strip off the "https : //example.com/" part.  This allows for the next 8 chars to be represented in the metadata min and max values.  It's easy to add and maintains relevance to the id value.  But you will need to use this column in the WHERE clause of the queries to have any benefit.  Changing queries can take a while.

Comment: Another option would be to just change the definition of the id column to not have the "https : //example.com/" leading characters.  The queries would still likely need to be changed as the fixed strings will also need to have this leading text removed.  However do this does change the data model.

Comment: I'd stay away from making a BIGINT column as you will want the sort order of this new column to match the sort order of id.  There are some BIG-ENDIAN / LITTLE-ENDIAN factors at play here so starting with byte sized data and ending up with word sized data that sorts the same will likely lead to some issue or corner cases.  Best to stick with varchar for the new column and avoid all this potential pain.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent guidance, Mr. @BillWeiner. 

We have experimentaly tried using an interleaved sort key, but abandoned the idea due to a significant increase in data volume. We've decided to proceed with creating a new column, id_key (varchar), and will implement your suggestions. We're extremely grateful for your assistance!